# When trying to get innerHTML, result is always undefined

Tags: javascript, events, undefined, innerhtml

I am generating some div's and appending to the DOM with this function

```
//Run forEach method on newObj(cats from local storage) to populate and append template to the DOM
    function getTheCats() {
        //Limiting the results to 3.  Probably better way to do this.
        newObj.slice(0, 3).forEach(cat => {
            const catEl = document.createElement('div')
            catEl.classList.add('cat-detail')
            catEl.innerHTML = `
            <div class="img-id-container" id="pointer-control" onclick="getCatDeets()">
            <img class='cat-image' src='${cat.thumbnail_url}' alt="Cat Pic"/>
            <h3 class="id-left">Cat ${cat.id}</h3>
            </div>
            <p class="birthday-left">${cat.birthdate}</p>
            `
            mainLeft.appendChild(catEl)
        })
    }
    getTheCats()
```

I am trying to log to console, some of the innerHTML when I click on one of the results.
I always get 'undefined' as a result.  I know I am missing something, but I can't seem to figure out what.  Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
    function myFunction(event) {
        const clickedCat = event.target.nodeName;
        console.log(clickedCat);
        const details = clickedCat.innerHTML
        console.log(details)
      }
```

Comment: Try `event.target.innerHTML`. `clickedCat` isn't `target`, it's `.target.nodeName`. The `.nodeName` is messing you up I think.

Comment: David784, you're right!  Thank you!!!

Answer (score 1):

From David784 in the comments,

I unnecessarily added .nodeName to event.target
I replaced it with .innerHTML and I am able to retrieve the data I need.

```
function myFunction(event) {
        const clickedCat = event.target.innerHTML;
        console.log(clickedCat);
        const details = clickedCat.innerHTML
        console.log(details)
      }
```